# Does a black hole evaporate by the time an observer reaches the singularity?

Tags: general-relativity, black-holes, observers, event-horizon, thought-experiment

Assume you are an invincible observer who falls into a blackhole...

Your time runs slower than the universe outside, as you get closer and closer to the singularity, the ratio between your time and the time of the universe outside the blackhole increases exponentially.

Ergo, you will see the universe in a very rapid "fast-forward" (ignore the fact that you'll get fried by the immense amount of radiation that accumulates due to the time dilation).

Does this also not mean that the event horizon is aging much faster than you, and thus evaporating, and as you get closer and closer to the singularity, it evaporates more and more per second, according to you and at some point it will catch up to you?

Also by the time you reach infinitesimally close to the singularity, the universe outside has experienced such a long time, that the heat death or the big crunch has happened, in which case the black hole is also gone?

TLDR; As you approach the singularity, the event horizon will start moving towards you as it shrinks, at some point it will catch up right?